# Multiple for loops with seperate arrays using ngFor

Tags: angular

I have two arrays, one is sizes and another is products. If i select any product from products array, then if size is available on that product then i am displaying size chart from sizes array.

In the below given stackblitz link issue is, Sizes are available for two products for that reason size chart display twice. But i want to show size chart only one time.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3te5sk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  products = [{ productname: "shirt", size: "L" }, { productname: "pant", size: "M" }, { productname: "phone", size: "" }]
  sizes = [{ size: "L" }, { size: "M" }, { size: "S" }, { size: "XL" }, { size: "XXL" }]
}
```

App.component.html:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show">
    <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let prod of products;let i=index">
        Sizes
        <div *ngIf="prod.size.length>0">
            <div *ngFor="let x of sizes">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <label >{{x.size}}</label>
              </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
          </div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

      <!-- If i use <label >{{sizes[i].size}}</label> It shows only L, M-->
```

Please help.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question

Comment: *If i select any product from products array*: how would you do that? There's nothing in the code allowing to select a product. It lists all the products, and that's all.

Comment: No, Just i gave relevant code. here i used two ngFor loops. For that reason sizes are getting based products length. But i need to get size chart only one time.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: If you need to dipslya the sizes only once, then put the loop on sizes outside of the loop on products, not inside.

Comment: Do you want to show the size of each product? or to display in one list all the sizes of the products? or maybe something else?

Comment: If i put the loop in outside then if condition will not work.

Comment: First of all, your `product` object has property `size` which is a string and not an array. How do you plan to map multiple sizes for each object. Make that an array and once a product is checked, show its sizes.

Comment: @Michal S... No i wrote the code based on if condition. Now sizes are displaying twice because i have two products. But i need to show sizes only one time.

Comment: *If i put the loop in outside then if condition will not work*: It would work if you tested the condition on the **selected** product. But to do that, you'd have to actually select a product, which why I asked, in my first comment, how you planned to select a product. Start by implementing the product selection. You can't display a chart based on a selected product if there is no selected product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the productlist for determining when to show size list for that product. In the code below, there is a `checkbox` for `products` which lets us **select** a product,  based on which we can check the size property of the selected `product` and if it's not empty we can show the size chart under it.

App.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  products = [{ productname: "shirt", size: "L" }, 
             { productname: "pant", size: "M" }, 
             { productname: "phone", size: "" }];
  sizes = [{ size: "L" }, { size: "M" }, 
          { size: "S" }, { size: "XL" }, { size: "XXL" }];

}
```

App.component.html:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show">
    <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let prod of products;let i=index">
        <input type="checkbox" 
           name="prod.productname" 
           [(ngModel)]="prod.checked">{{prod.productname |uppercase}}
      <div *ngIf="prod.checked && prod.size != ''"" 
            style="background-color: cyan;  margin-left:2rem">
        <b>Sizes available:</b> <div *ngFor="let x of sizes">
            <input type="checkbox">
                    <label >{{x.size}}</label>
        </div>
  </div> 
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.